# How do I change a header of HTML with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in HTML and in JavaScript. I have a simple HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blah</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h3 class="test">Heading</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need to do, is that when I click on a heading, it should prompt a question: "Are you sure that you want to change the heading?" And when OK is clicked, it should change the heading to the user entered value. So far I have figured out how to get that popup box working (js file below), but I'm struggling to figure out how to change the heading after I click OK?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
    var confirmIt = function (e) {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) e.preventDefault();
     };
    for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
        elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `this.textContent = "new heading"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example using `PROMPT` instead of `confirm`.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
    var confirmIt = function (e) {
        val = prompt("Are you sure that you want to change the heading");
      if(val != "" && val != null){
        this.textContent  = val;
        }
     };
    for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
        elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blah</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h3 class="test">Heading</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```